# string comprehension in python and conversion

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I have a character list of for instance

```
x = ['100','2','3','4']
```

and I converted it into a string using `str(x)` I get the output as

```
"['100','2','3','4']"
```

what operation should I do get the output as

```
['100','2','3','4']
```

Comment: You want a result same as the input? Please update the question with more detailed explanation about the problem and the code that you've tried before?

Comment: You can do `print(x)`

Comment: i am storing this data as x=['100','2','3','4'] in a file, then i must read this file and convert it as ['100','2','3','4']

Comment: If you want to store python lists in file, then you should try in-built [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) package. Pickle package can be used to store python objects to file.

Comment: If you're storing simple data formats like this, something like [json](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#module-json) would probably be a better choice than pickle.

Comment: You do **not** "get the output as" what you show. `x = str(x)`, followed by `print(x)` shows that `x` contains *exactly* what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to simply use the `eval()` built-in function, as follows:

```
myString ="['100','2','3','4']"
print(type(myString))  # <class 'str'>

myList = eval(myString)
print(type(myList))    # <class 'list'>
print(myList)          # ['100', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am storing this data as `x = ['100','2','3','4']` in a file, then I
> must read this file and convert it as `['100','2','3','4']`.

Conversion to string is **not** the solution to your problem. To store a list efficiently, you need to preserve data types. A csv or text file would also be inappropriate, unless you want to store data type definitions separately.

Instead, use `pickle` to save and read lists (Python-only solution):

```
import pickle

with open('list_pickled.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(x, f)
```

Then pick up again when required:

```
with open('list_pickled.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    x_new = pickle.load(f)
```